# Jupyter notebook markdown without mouse click

Tags: jupyter-notebook

For markdown there is a shortcut like typing a number(1,2,3,4..) in command mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and then giving an <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The thing is that your cursor gets before the "###" (if you used <kbd>3</kbd>) where you also need to click the <kbd>End</kbd> key to be able to write.

Is there a way to overcome the last action as it is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What you already have is a one click solution, which is going to be hard to beat. The only improvement I can think of is to override the functionality that's inserting the markdown headings for you. You could extend it to also place the cell in edit mode and move the cursor to the end. This would be placed in your `custom.js` file, which you place here: `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`.